# Move a method to another method java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hw4Part4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//Ask for the diners’ satisfaction level using these ratings: 1 = Totally satisfied, 2 = Satisfied,
//3 = Dissatisfied.
    System.out.println("Satisfacion leve: ");
    int satisfactionNumber= sc.nextInt();

//Ask for the bill subtotal (not including the tip)
    System.out.println("What is the bill subtotal: ");
    double subtotal= sc.nextInt();  

//Report the satisfaction level and bill total.
   System.out.println("The satisfaction level is: "+ satisfactionLevel(satisfactionNumber));

System.out.println("The bill total is: " + getBillTotal(tipPercentage, subtotal));

    }


public static String satisfactionLevel(int satisfactionNumber){

String satisfactionL = "";

if (satisfactionNumber == 1){
    satisfactionL ="Totally-satisfied"; 
}

if (satisfactionNumber == 2){
   satisfactionL = "Satisfied";
}
if (satisfactionNumber == 3){
   satisfactionL = "Dissatisfied";
}
return satisfactionL;

}

//This method takes the satisfaction number and returns the percentage of tip to be 
//calculated based on the number.
//This method will return a value of 0.20, 0.15, or 0.10

public static double getPercentage(int satisfactionNumber){


double getPercentage = 0;
if (satisfactionNumber ==1){
    getPercentage = 0.20;
}
if (satisfactionNumber ==2){
    getPercentage = 0.15;
}
if (satisfactionNumber ==3){
    getPercentage = 0.10;
}
return getPercentage;
}   


public static double getBillTotal(double tipPercentage, double subtotal){

double totalWithTip= (subtotal + ( getPercentage(satisfactionNumber) * subtotal));
return totalWithTip;

}
    }
```

I am having issues on the last method, the whole code is shown above.

It says there is error with the part where I am trying to use the previous method.

I need to get the percentage which was computed on the previous method.

Comment: Are you missing underscores in that code?  Also, where is the method declarations for both methods?

Comment: Focus on getting it to actually compile first, you can't just randomly embed spaces inside identifiers.

Comment: We can't help much without the other code and the actual errors you see.

Comment: The whole code was added

Comment: Post the error message as well

Comment: satisfactionNumber cannot be resolve to a variable...

Comment: double totalWithTip= (subtotal + ( getPercentage(satisfactionNumber) * subtotal));
return totalWithTip;

}
    }

Comment: And also on System.out.println("The bill total is: " + getBillTotal(tipPercentage, subtotal));

Comment: It says the same thing, tipPercentage cannot be resolved to a varible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this part of the code:

```
public static double getBillTotal(double tipPercentage, double subtotal){
    double totalWithTip= (subtotal + ( getPercentage(satisfactionNumber) * subtotal));
    return totalWithTip;
}
```

You call this method:

```
getPercentage(satisfactionNumber)
```

However, this variable:

```
satisfactionNumber
```

Doesn't exist in this method's scope.  You should pass this variable to the method as so:

```
public static double getBillTotal(double tipPercentage, double subtotal, int satisfactionNumber){
    double totalWithTip= (subtotal + ( getPercentage(satisfactionNumber) * subtotal));
    return totalWithTip;
}
```

So when you call the method in the `main`, you pass it in:

```
System.out.println("The bill total is: " + getBillTotal(tipPercentage, subtotal, satisfactionNumber));
```

> tipPercentage cannot be resolved to a varible

Pretty much any variable you pass in, you must create.  So when you do the above line, make sure you have all variables delcared:

```
double tipPercentage, subtotal, satisfactionNumber;
//now set these three variables with a value before passing it to the method
System.out.println("The bill total is: " + getBillTotal(tipPercentage, subtotal, satisfactionNumber));
```

Comment: On the main method is says of System.out.println("The bill total is: " + getBillTotal(tipPercentage, subtotal, satisfactionNumber)); now says that tipPercentage cannot be resolved to a variable :(

Comment: You need to define that variable.  You don't have it declared either.  How will the computer program know what it is without you telling it what it is?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but I think you need to remove whitespace:

```
double totalWithTip = subtotal + (getPercentage(satisfactionNumber) * subtotal);
return totalWithTip;
```

This code assumes a variable:

```
int satisfactionNumber;
```

and a method:

```
double getPercentage(int satisfactionNumber) {
    // some impl
}
```

Comment: This is assuming he's mixing up terminology for methods with variables.

Comment: I am with @Bohemian - it looks like they are adding whitespace where it doesn't belong.